# Q&A Platform similar to Stack Exchange model?

Tags: webapp-rec

I absolutely love the Stack Exchange model for asking Questions and voting on answers.

I have been looking at different forum platforms and at the moment I am considering either [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/), but likely to lean towards [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com) (with some Mods like Resolved and Reputation bolted on)

Am I missing something?  I saw some websites like [Splunk Answers](http://answers.splunk.com/) and [Pods](http://podscms.org/qna/) have a near identical design to SE.
**- Is there a free platform/template out there that mimics the Stack Exchange platform?**

I saw [Stacked](http://ra-ajax.org/stacked-an-open-source-implementation-of-stackoverflow-com), but 1st impressions it looked a bit rookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/59303) on Meta Stack Overflow.

It has a comprehensive list of clones with which technologies they use etc.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-solutions-to-create-a-question-answer-website/

Answer (score 0):

Another site with an overview of similar web apps: http://www.webappers.com/2010/02/26/stack-overflow-like-open-source-qa-systems-for-download/

Comment: Is their a clear winner in these apps?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet if you don't want to pay anything is OSQA.net or http://shapado.com.

But if you'd like a solution where you don't have to bother about hosting or upgrades or complicated installations, then I suggest you check out my companys platform called http://answerbase.com.